# Additional information for Collapsible Force Layout Visualization of D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wish to use the [Collapsible Force Layout visualization](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) offered by D3.

[image]

I am a novice at using D3.js and wasn't able to locate the flare.json that was being used to render the demo visualization. Is there a way to get the file?

Also, can this graph be used to work with datasets where a node may have more than one parent? (That is, two or more nodes might have the same child node). Is there a way to edit the code to suit this requirement?

The code being used on the sample page is as under:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">

circle.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>
      Flare code size<br>
      force-directed graph
    </h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.geom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var w = 1280,
    h = 800,
    node,
    link,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function(d) { return d._children ? -d.size / 100 : -30; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 80 : 30; })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  root.fixed = true;
  root.x = w / 2;
  root.y = h / 2 - 80;
  update();
});

function update() {
  var nodes = flatten(root),
      links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Update the nodes…
  node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .style("fill", color);

  node.transition()
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; });

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.children ? 4.5 : Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update();
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [], i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + recurse(v); }, 0);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
    return node.size;
  }

  root.size = recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any guidance and help on this question will be highly appreciated. I need this for my research project.

Comment: flare.json is here: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1093025

Comment: The force layout itself doesn't place any restrictions on how nodes are connected, but for the collapsible version it doesn't really make sense to have more than one parent for collapsible nodes.